# Why eth0 and eth1 is up after 10 minutes login screen appears

Tags: centos, networking, ip, ip-address

Question is

First question: Why I need to wait for the link is up for eno3 for 5 minutes and eno4 for 10 minutes after login screen appear. is it something I can do about it ?  If I try manually up any of eth it gives me error message link is not ready.

Second Question: Is it possible that hosting company setup the way this server  has to be connected their equipment via ip6 then ip4 if so Do I need to setup ipv6 as static to eliminate this problem ?

prior to centos login screen I can see no any routing.

```
[root@gtw4-ab ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

After 5 minutes first ethernet is automaticially up

```
ixgbe 0000:01:00.1 eno4 NIC link is up 10gbps flow control rx-tx
IPv6 ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno4 link becomes ready

[root@gtw4-ab ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eno4
```

after 10 minutes second ethernet is up

```
ixgbe 0000:01:00.1 eno3 NIC link is up 10gbps flow control rx-tx
IPv6 ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno3 link becomes ready

[root@gtw4-ab ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         91.115.6.254    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno3
91.115.6.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno3
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eno4
```

ip address

```
[root@gtw4-ab ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:77:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 91.115.6.100/32 scope global noprefixroute eno3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxx:77a2/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:x:77:a3 brd xx:x:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.20/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eno4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 xxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:77a3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Eno3

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=91.115.6.100
PREFIX=32
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=eno3
UUID=xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-881f-xxxxxxxxxxx
DEVICE=eno3
ONBOOT=yes
AUTOCONNECT_PRIORITY=-999
GATEWAY=91.115.6.254
```

eno4

```
DEVICE=eno4
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.0.20
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
```

systemd

## systemd-analyze blame

```
      6.037s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      4.528s cloud-init-local.service
      3.892s dracut-initqueue.service
      2.935s initrd-switch-root.service
      2.206s kdump.service
      1.459s sssd.service
      1.383s systemd-udev-settle.service
      1.090s polkit.service
       985ms tuned.service
       797ms cloud-init.service
       658ms cloud-final.service
       571ms cloud-config.service
       542ms gluster.mount
       479ms systemd-journald.service
       426ms boot.mount
       386ms data.mount
       379ms sysroot.mount
       367ms systemd-logind.service
```

Comment: Try looking at `systemd-analyze blame` output (run as root). That will show you startup times of services and you can look what took long.

Comment: thanks Jeff, according to this command I got result following   
     6.037s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          4.528s cloud-init-local.service
          3.892s dracut-initqueue.service
          2.935s initrd-switch-root.service
          2.206s kdump.service
          1.459s sssd.service
          1.383s systemd-udev-settle.service
          1.090s polkit.service
           985ms tuned.service
           797ms cloud-init.service
           658ms cloud-final.service
           571ms cloud-config.service
           542ms gluster.mount

Comment: apparently not order but some networking issue I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turnout to be defect motherboard they changed and its now work perfectly